# How to implement dependency between asynchronous functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, dependencies, deferred

As a simplified case, I have two async functions, `foo` and `bar`. `bar` needs the result of `foo`, i.e. `bar` depends on `foo`. I have no idea about which function will be called first.

1. If `bar` is invoked first, `bar` will call `foo` and start itself right after `foo` is done.
2. If `foo` is invoked first and done, `bar` can use the result of `foo`.
3. If `foo` is invoked first and `bar` is invoked before `foo` is done, `bar` needs to wait for `foo`'s result. (Don't invoke a new call to `foo`, just wait for the already-fired call to `foo`)

How can I achieve this?
Is it possible to register an async function dependency chain (something like the dependency in require.js `define['foo'], function() { bar(); }`)?
Can I use `$.deferred()` to achieve it?
How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In circumstances like this, the standard approach is to cache the lower level promise.

Typically you will establish, in some suitable outer scope, a js plain object as a promise cache, and always look there first before calling your async process.

```
var promiseCache = {};

function foo() {
    if(!promiseCache.foo) {
        promiseCache.foo = doSomethingAsync();
    }
    return promiseCache.foo;
}

function bar() {
    return foo().then(doSomethingElseAsync);
}
```

Of course, there's nothing to prevent you also caching the higher level promise, if appropriate.

```
function bar() {
    if(!promiseCache.bar) {
        promiseCache.bar = foo().then(doSomethingElseAsync);
    }
    return promiseCache.bar;
}
```

**EDIT: `forceRefresh` feature**

You can force a function to refresh its cached promise by passing an (extra) parameter.

```
function foo(any, number, of, other, arguments, forceRefresh) {
    if(forceRefresh || !promiseCache.foo) {
        promiseCache.foo = doSomethingAsync();
    }
    return promiseCache.foo;
}
```

By making `forceRefresh` the last argument, leaving it out is the same as passing `false` and `foo` will use the cached promise if available. Alternatively, pass `true` to guarantee that `doSomethingAsync()` be called and the cached value be refreshed.

**EDIT 2: setName()/getName()**

With the `forceRefresh` mechanism in place in `getName()` :

```
setName(newName).then(getName.bind(null, true)); //set new name then read it back using forceRefresh.
```

Alternatively, omit the `forceRefresh` mechanism and, assuming the cache property to be `promiseCache.name` :

```
setName(newName).then(function() {
    promiseCache.name = $.when(newName);//update the cache with a simulated `getName()` promise.
});
```

The first method is more elegant, the second more efficient.

Comment: Thx. I'm using your approach. A follow-up question: If there is a function `setFoo` that will change the value returned by your `foo` function, how would you make change accordingly? My idea is add `promiseCache.foo = $.when(newFoo)` into `setFoo`.

Comment: @Moon , I think you are describing a `forceRefresh` feature. I've made an edit.

Comment: Thx. In my case, I have function `getName` and `setName` and I save `getName` in `promiseCache`. `setName` will send ajax to server to set `name`. If `setName` is successful, I don't want to `forceRefresh` `getName`, but update `getName`'s promise.

Comment: @Moon, take a look at Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply think of both functions as independent. That way, you don't go daisy-chaining dependencies that operate asynchronously. You can then have one other module that uses them.

Since they do async stuff, consider using promises. You can use jQuery's deferreds for compatibility. Think of deferreds as read/write while promises are read-only.

```
// foo.js
define(function(){
  return function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      // Do async stuff. Call resolve/reject accordingly
    });
  };
});

// bar.js
define(function(){
  return function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      // Do async stuff. Call resolve/reject accordingly
    });
  };
});

// Your code (Excuse the CommonJS format. Personal preference)
define(function(require){

  // Require both functions
  var foo = require('foo');
  var bar = require('bar');

  // Use them
  foo(...).then(function(response){
    return bar();
  }).then(function(){
    // all done
  });;

});
```

Comment: Thx for your explanation on 'Think of deferreds as read/write while promises are read-only.' but your solution is a little bit expensive I think. I have lots of `foo, bar` etc., each of which I need to create a js file.

Comment: @Moon That's how modules work. The number of files is irrelevant. RequireJS also has an optimizer that bundles dependencies into one file.

Comment: @Jonseph. Yes. But in my case, some of the functions logically belong to one module. I tend not to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an object property with possible values `undefined` , `"pending"` , `true` ; call `deferred.resolve()` when `obj.active` is `true` , `deferred.reject()` when `obj.active` is "pending"

```js
var res = {
  active: void 0
};

var foo = function foo(state) {
  var t;
  var deferred = function(type) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        
        if (res.active === "pending" || state && state === "pending") {
          res.active = "pending";
          dfd.rejectWith(res, [res.active])
        } else {
          res.active = state || "pending";
          t = setInterval(function() {
            console.log(res.active)
          }, 100);
            setTimeout(function() {
              clearInterval(t)
              res.active = true;
              dfd.resolveWith(res, [res.active])
            }, 3000);
        }
        return dfd.promise()
      })
      .then(function(state) {
        console.log("foo value", state);
        return state
      }, function(err) {
        console.log("foo status", err)
        return err
      })
  }
  return deferred()
}

var bar = function bar(result) {
  var deferred = function(type) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
      if (result && result === true) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          dfd.resolveWith(result, [true])
        }, 1500)
      } else {
        dfd.rejectWith(res, [res.active || "pending"])
      };
      return dfd.promise()
    })
  }
  return deferred().then(function(data) {
    console.log("bar value", data);
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("bar status", err);
  })
}

$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).is(":first") 
  ? foo().then(bar, bar) 
  : bar(res.active === true ? res.active : "pending")
    .then(foo, foo).then(bar, bar)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>foo</button>
<button>bar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood correctly the question. But here is my take at it:

- Put you function foo into a variable

  `var foo_fn = function foo(foo_args){// Your async code goes here}`
- foo is async and returns something at some point. In your definition of foo, I recommend that you use promises, the concept is designed to manage composition of asynchronous functions in a clean and scalable way. jQuery implementation of the concept is convenient in a lot of simple use cases but suffers from some drawbacks which make it interesting for you at some point to use one of the many promises library which follow the Promises/A specification. For more information, you can refer to :
  Cf. https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/javascript-promises-and-why-jquery-implementation-is-broken/ and https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises
- so, say foo takes args, and returns a promise which later resolves into some value.

  `var foo_fn = function foo(foo_args) {
     return foo_fn.promise = new RSVP.Promise (resolve, reject) {

       // Your async code goes here
     }
   }`

  Here I use the RSVP promise library but any promise library following the Promises/A specification could do the job.
- When bar is called, you can just do:

  ``` function bar (bar_args) {
   var foo_promise = foo_fn.promise;
   // if foo was called, whether the computation is in progress or finished,
   // the foo_fn.promise field will be non-empty, as foo returns immediately
   // with a promise anytime it is called
   `` 
   if (!foo.promise) {
     // foo has not yet been called so call it
     foo_promise = foo(foo_args);
   }
   foo_promise.then (function (foo_result) {/*some async code here*/})
  } ```

NOTE : That solution is quite similar to the one proposed by `Roamer-1888`. One difference is that in Roamer proposal, the `foo` function will always return the same value after performing once its asyncronous computation. Don't know if this is the intended behaviour. In my implementation, foo executes the async. computation every time it is called. `bar` will use the latest computed value that is stored in the field `foo_fn.promise`. Older computations are lost, possible computation in progress is not taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have this pattern often used in your code, you can also create a function working on the model of the `define`
 function in `require.js`.

You will need :

- a registry to hold the dependencies functions (`foo` in your example)
- the dependant function (`bar` in your example) will need to accept the dependencies functions computed value as part of their signature. For example, a hash of the dependencies could be passed as first parameter, so bar signature could be: `{foo: foo_result}, other_bar_args...`
- the dependencies function must follow the model of my previous answer, i.e. register their promise value as a property on themselves when they execute.
- Reminder : you need to name those dependencies functions to reference them inside their body, and then add that object to the registry.

In the `define` function body, you wrap the dependent function into another one which :

- Get all dependencies from the registry
- Get all dependencies values, executing the dependencies when necessary (similarly to my previous answer). This means you end up having a list of promises, whose results you then congregate together (`RSVP.hash` for example with RSVP promise library). I believe jQuery has a similar function with `jQuery.when`
- you call the dependent function (`bar`) with this hash of results as a first argument, other arguments being the same as the wrapped function
- that wrapped function is the new `bar`, so when `bar` is called, it will be the wrapped function which will be called.

A bit lengthy but it should work. If you want to see some code, let me know if this is what you were looking for. In any case, if you are going to have complex async. in your code, it could be interesting for you to use a compliant promise library. $.deferred is also to be used only when you have nothing better at sight as it makes it harder for you to track the behaviour of your functions : you need to keep track of all places where this deferred appears to be able to reason about your program.